# Processing xml file taking lot of time in.net

Tags: c#, xml, linq, oop, console-application

I have an XML file where data is scattered over. I have to get all cells value which reside in under XML tag `<managedObject class="JTS"`, dependent site information scattered over XML tag `<managedObject class="CCF"`, and other dependent power information are scattered over XML tag `<managedObject class="POC"`. I am using `XmlReader.ReadFrom` to take the small section and processing, but now the issue is the XML is big for each cell, site and power information, and for it I am reading the entire big XML file each time, which is bad logic and taking lot of time. Is there any way I can load all the cells(say 5000 cells) into classes and corresponding sites, power what ever information required for cells in to the classes and then process the classes by using `foreach` iteration. The code and XML snippet I am using is as below

```xml
<managedObject class="JTS" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500">
  <p name="name">VM_25261_G1_A</p>
  <p name="cellBarQualify">0</p>
  <p name="cellBarred">0</p>
  <p name="cId">25261</p>
  <p name="hoppingMode">1</p>
  <p name="hoppingSequenceNumber1">54</p>

  <managedObject class="CCF" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500">
    <p name="name">ET_AR_G_0267_GHABATGHAYATI</p>
    <p name="SBTSId">10267</p>
    <p name="abisInterfaceConnectionType">2</p>
    <p name="adminState">1</p>

    <managedObject class="POC" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500">
      <p name="alpha">0</p>
      <p name="bepPeriod">10</p>
      <p name="bsTxPwrMax">0</p>
      <p name="bsTxPwrMax1x00">0</p>
```

And the code

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(path, settings))
{
    xr.MoveToContent();
    while (xr.Read())
    {
        while (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.LocalName == "managedObject" && xr.GetAttribute("class") == "JTS")
        {
            dist_name = xr.GetAttribute("distName");
            dist_name_ori = dist_name;
            XElement pin = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
            cell_name = GetValueForNokia(pin, "name");
            DataTable dtSiteDetails = GetSiteDetails2G(path, dist_name, settings);
            DataTable dtBasePowrDetails = GetBasePowrDetails2G(path, dist_name_ori, settings);


private static DataTable GetSiteDetails2G(string path, string cell_nametomatchwith_sitename, XmlReaderSettings settings)
{
    DataTable dt = null;

    try
    {
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(path, settings))
        {
            xr.MoveToContent();
            while (xr.Read())
            {
                while (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.LocalName == "managedObject" && xr.GetAttribute("class") == "CCF")
                {
                    distname = xr.GetAttribute("distName");
                    XElement pin = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
                    if (distname == cell_nametomatchwith_sitename)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                        dr[0] = xr.GetAttribute("version");
                        dr[1] = GetValueForNokia(pin, "name");
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if (done)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    return dt;
}

private static DataTable GetBasePowrDetails2G(string path, string cell_nametomatchwith_POC, XmlReaderSettings settings)
{

    try
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("bsTxPwrMax");
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(path, settings))
        {
            xr.MoveToContent();
            while (xr.Read())
            {
                while (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.LocalName == "managedObject" && xr.GetAttribute("class") == "POC")
                {
                    distname = xr.GetAttribute("distName");

                    XElement pin = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
                    if (distname == cell_nametomatchwith_POC)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                        dr[0] = GetValueForNokia(pin, "bsTxPwrMax");
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if (done)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    return dt;
}

private static string GetValueForNokia(XElement pin, string input)
{
    XNamespace ns = "raml20.xsd";
    var output = pin.Descendants(ns + "p").FirstOrDefault(
        p => p.Attributes("name").FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value == input) != null
    );
    return output == null ? null : output.Value;

}
```

Here I have two cells `PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500/BTS-123` and `PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404501/BTS-123` in XML snippet, like this I have 5000 cells

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <managedObject class="JTS" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500/BTS-123">
    <p name="name">VM_25261_G1_A</p>
    <p name="cellBarQualify">0</p>
    <p name="cellBarred">0</p>
    <p name="cId">25261</p>
    <p name="hoppingMode">1</p>
    <p name="hoppingSequenceNumber1">54</p>
  </managedObject>
.
.
  <managedObject class="CCF" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500">
    <p name="name">ET_AR_G_0267_GHABATGHAYATI</p>
    <p name="SBTSId">10267</p>
    <p name="abisInterfaceConnectionType">2</p>
    <p name="adminState">1</p>
  </managedObject>
.
.
  <managedObject class="POC" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500">
    <p name="alpha">0</p>
    <p name="bepPeriod">10</p>
    <p name="bsTxPwrMax">0</p>
    <p name="bsTxPwrMax1x00">0</p>
  </managedObject>

  <managedObject class="JTS" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404501/BTS-123">
    <p name="name">VM_25262_G1_A</p>
    <p name="cellBarQualify">0</p>
    <p name="cellBarred">0</p>
    <p name="cId">25262</p>
    <p name="hoppingMode">1</p>
    <p name="hoppingSequenceNumber1">54</p>
  </managedObject>
.
.
  <managedObject class="CCF" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404501">
    <p name="name">ET_AR_G_0267_GHABATGHAYATI</p>
    <p name="SBTSId">10267</p>
    <p name="abisInterfaceConnectionType">2</p>
    <p name="adminState">1</p>
  </managedObject>
.
.
  <managedObject class="POC" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404501">
    <p name="alpha">0</p>
    <p name="bepPeriod">10</p>
    <p name="bsTxPwrMax">10</p>
    <p name="bsTxPwrMax1x00">0</p>
  </managedObject>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a combination of XmlReader and Xml Linq.  The code below puts elements into a dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication63
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "managedObject")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("managedObject");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement managedObject = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);

                    ManagedObject newObject = new ManagedObject();
                    ManagedObject.objects.Add(newObject);

                    newObject.mClass = (string)managedObject.Attribute("class");
                    newObject.distName = (string)managedObject.Attribute("distName");
                    newObject.hierachy = newObject.distName.Split(new char[] { '/' });

                    newObject.objectdict = managedObject.Elements()
                        .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => (string)y)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
                }
            }
            ManagedObjectNode.CreateTree();
        }
        public class ManagedObject
        {
            public static List<ManagedObject> objects = new List<ManagedObject>();

            public Dictionary<string, string> objectdict { get; set; }

            public string distName { get; set; }
            public string mClass { get; set; }

            public string[] hierachy { get; set; }
        }
        public class ManagedObjectNode
        {
            public static ManagedObjectNode root = new ManagedObjectNode();

            public Dictionary<string, ManagedObjectNode> children { get; set; }
            public List<ManagedObject> leaves { get; set; }
            public string nodeName { get; set; }

            public static void CreateTree()
            {
                root.nodeName = "root";
                GetTreeRecursive(root, ManagedObject.objects, 0);
            }
            public static void GetTreeRecursive(ManagedObjectNode parent, List<ManagedObject> mObjects, int level)
            {
                var groups = mObjects.GroupBy(x => x.hierachy[level]).ToList();
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    ManagedObjectNode newNode = new ManagedObjectNode();
                    newNode.nodeName = group.Key;
                    if (parent.children == null) parent.children = new Dictionary<string, ManagedObjectNode>();
                    parent.children.Add(group.Key, newNode);
                    newNode.leaves = group.Where(x => x.hierachy.Count() - 1 == level).ToList();
                    List<ManagedObject> hasChildren = group.Where(x => x.hierachy.Count() - 1 > level).ToList();
                    if (hasChildren.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        GetTreeRecursive(newNode, hasChildren, level + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xml I used

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <managedObject class="JTS" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500">
    <p name="name">VM_25261_G1_A</p>
    <p name="cellBarQualify">0</p>
    <p name="cellBarred">0</p>
    <p name="cId">25261</p>
    <p name="hoppingMode">1</p>
    <p name="hoppingSequenceNumber1">54</p>
  </managedObject>

  <managedObject class="CCF" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500">
    <p name="name">ET_AR_G_0267_GHABATGHAYATI</p>
    <p name="SBTSId">10267</p>
    <p name="abisInterfaceConnectionType">2</p>
    <p name="adminState">1</p>
  </managedObject>

  <managedObject class="POC" version="BSC17" distName="PLMN-PLMN/BSC-404500">
    <p name="alpha">0</p>
    <p name="bepPeriod">10</p>
    <p name="bsTxPwrMax">0</p>
    <p name="bsTxPwrMax1x00">0</p>
  </managedObject>
</root>
```

Comment: i am checking this,i will update you.Because here only one cell of tag <managedObject class="JTS",like this i have 5000 cells ,I edited my question

Comment: You just need to use an IF statement and test distName in my code.  You can use if(distName.StartsWith("PLMN-PLMN/BSC")){......}

Comment: ,this is same as my answer,suppose i have 5000 cell,for each cell here i  have to read the entire big file everytime ,ie 5000 times,But what i want is create a nested structure by using OOPS class concept and store all 5000 cells and dependent information by reading big xml file one time .

Comment: Then process the collection by iterating it

Comment: ,i am checking it doing some manupulation.Will update you.many thanks

Comment: There was an issue with the code that was bothering me all night.  Couldn't sleep so I fixed it.  See modified code above.  Original code only worked if every branch had same number of descendants.  Now fix code will place leaves on each descendant.